# My exception handing is not working

Tags: c#

When a user enters a string the program breaks and my exception handling is not picking up this problem. What am I doing wrong ?

```
int number;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age");

number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

try
{
    if (number >= 18)
     Console.WriteLine("You are old enough to enter");
    else if (number < 18)
     Console.WriteLine("You are not old enough to enter");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Only enter a number");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: If it fails outside the `try` block `catch` won't catch it.

Comment: please search before asking

Answer (score 1):

You have to put

```
number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

inside Try/Catch too. You are reading a string and trying to convert it to int. When it's not possible Convert.ToInt32 will throw an exception.

```
    try
    {
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (number >= 18)
            Console.WriteLine("You are old enough to enter");
        else if (number < 18)
            Console.WriteLine("You are not old enough to enter");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Only enter a number");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Also, would recommend you using int.TryParse(). In that case, you can check the result without catching an exception.

Comment: Correct answer and a good hint at using TryParse, no? Why downvote without any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your code to place `try .. catch` on a right place, you placed this line:

`number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

out of `try .. catch` block and that's reason why your exception is not handled, check the code below:

```
{
      try
      {
        int number;


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age");
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number >= 18)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("You are old enough to enter");
        }
        else if(number < 18)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("You are not old enough to enter");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Only enter a number");

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

More about **try..catch** [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch).

Comment: Wow, who's been down voting all of these answers?

Comment: @Andez well you have chance to change it, vote it up :D

Answer (score -1):

```
number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Add this in the `try` block